# Can not play sound file Swift4

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation

I'm trying play simple .wav file in my application.
Here is the code:

```
func alarmSound() {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "emergency021", ofType: "wav") else {
        print("Can't find audio file")
        return
    }

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)
        if let prepare = player?.prepareToPlay() {
            print("Player prepared: \(prepare)")
        }
        player?.volume = 1.0
        player?.play()
    } catch {
        print("Playing sound error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Everything ok, file in the bundle, url is ok, player prepared, but.. there is no any sound. I have tried .mp3 file - same result.
Any ideas, why?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was declaring player: AVAudioPlayer locally in function body, when I moved it up to ViewController all works.